# isInstance() ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java

Following is my code which compiles fine but I am getting `ClassNotFoundException` for case 2 while running, my question is why I am getting error for case 2 :

## Case 1

command `java Var Var`

output `false`

## Case 2

command `java Var Object`

output `ClassNotFoundException : Object`

```
class Var
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Thread t = new Thread();
        System.out.println(Class.forName(args[0]).isInstance(t));
        
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The fully qualified class name is `java.lang.Object`. 
The compiler automatically imports java.lang.*, that's why you don't have to import classes from this package. However if you call `Class.forName` you have to use the fully qualified class name.